# IAM Policy not allowing me to upload to S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I am uploading a file to s3 using the following code:

```
s3.meta.client.upload_file(file_location, bucket_name, key,ExtraArgs={'ACL': 'public-read'})
```

When I use ACL: Public read, my code returns with the following error that I do not have permission to do this.

```
"errorMessage": "Failed to upload test.xlsx: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied"


"errorType": "S3UploadFailedError"
```

Below is an IAM policy attached to my user.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to also grant PutObjectAcl access? AWS Error messages are kinda unhelpful.

Comment: @JohnnesSouza I am new to AWS, so I am unfamiliar with what that is.

Comment: I think your bucket may not have the right permission configured. In the past I had the same issue, had to set it to public so I was able to upload some content. Check [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/set-bucket-permissions.html) for further info.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 block public access prevents the application of any settings that allow public access to data within S3 buckets. Right now ACL operation is denied.

Please turn on the
"Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new access control lists (ACLs)" settings from *Permissions >> Block Public access*

[image]